# How to connect to backend on EC2 with private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have my frontend and backend applications running via AWS ECS. The frontend EC2 instance has a public IP so that can be connected over the internet but the backend EC2 instance only has a private IP. Both the instances are in the same VPC with different subnets (Public and Private). I have already verified the route tables, NAT, NACL, and security group configurations and everything is as per the requirement. When my front end app hits the backend at private IP it gets a connection timeout i.e. unable to connect.

I've verified the connection by SSH into public instance and ping to private IP of backend instance, ping is fine. I also tried to curl from my frontend instance to backend API with private IP as host, I get the response, same thing is verified from the frontend docker container as well. But frontend app is not able to make a request to backend API.

[Check visual here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDJJT.png)

Comment: Did you test curl to the private API from within your frontend EC2 instance? If that works but your app, on the same instance, can't reach the API then your app is doing something different.

Comment: Is your front-end code actually running on the EC2 server? Or is it some sort of web app that actually runs in the browser?

Comment: @jarmod I have tested curl from frontend EC2 to private API and it is working, if you are saying there is some problem with the app, then I have also tried it with placing a blank html page and calling the private API there, still not working

Comment: @MarkB My frontend code is a web app in VueJs but it is server side rendered web app using Nuxt. That is why I deployed it in an EC2 instance not S3.

Comment: Are you sure that 100% of the API calls from the frontend to the backend happen when the UI is rendered on the server, before it is displayed in the web browser? If that was the case this would be an entirely static webapp.

Comment: I'm trying calling a login API, and that is when login form is rendered, then I enter creds and click login which calls API. So I think what you are asking is not the case

Answer (score 0):

Request timeout normally is caused by the security group problem.

Maybe it would be a good try to re-check the sg attached to the instance in the private subnet? make sure the public instance is allowed to talk to the private instance.

You can try to add the sg that attached to the public instance to the source of inbound rule of sg attached to the private instance. It will allow the public instance talk to the private instance regardless any change of IP address.

Comment: I have already verified the SG attached to public and private, and they are able to connect that is why I'm able to ping the private instance from public and also make curl request from public instance to private.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling the API from browser, so your current client is browser which can not access private IP of backend that is why it is showing unable to connect.
Solution is to expose backend also to Public IP and configure the same in frontend, then it will work. Thanks

Comment: Yes I understand that but I have backend private for a reason and I do not want to make it public.